# Imbalanced-learn import in Spyder fails after successful installation on Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have successfully installed Imbalanced learn package on Conda and have all dependencies available. however, when i try to import the package in Spyder, i get an attribute error saying AttributeError: type object 'sklearn.utils.seq_dataset.SequentialDataset64' has no attribute '**reduce_cython**'

I have tried reinstalling the package and have checked all dependencies and package versions. I have updated the scikit-learn package to the latest version

## I have installed imbalanced learn in the anaconda prompt using

conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn

## and then importing it in Spyder using

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

I expected a successful import but got the following error:

AttributeError: type object 'sklearn.utils.seq_dataset.SequentialDataset64' has no attribute '**reduce_cython**'

Comment: try updating numpy version.

Comment: Updated all dependencies and was able to import

Comment: This is an error raised by `scikit-learn`. Either the version of `scikit-learn` that you have is not compatible with `imbalanced-learn` (I don't think so since `conda` would check when installing `imbalanced-learn` since `scikit-learn` is one of the dependencies) or their something wrong with the `scikit-learn` version. I would try reinstalling `scikit-learn`.